# How to create thumbnails of the same size?

Tags: wordpress

Please [check here](http://career.guru99.com/category/resume-2/), how to set dimension of feature images uploaded in post and page?

See below image for what I actually want

[image]

Comment: try to pass the size in the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100))  this will display the image of size 100px;  on the other way you can get the wp_attachment_image_url() of  that post (you can check the function in wordpress codex)  and get the actual image url  and pass that in img src

Comment: where i have to pass  the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add below code in theme's function.php file

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
add_image_size( 'custom-image-thumb', 200, 200,true ); //200 pixels wide and 200 height, true for crop exact size and false for dimensional crop.
}
```

Then you can use this on front side like below code :

```
<?php echo $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'custom-image-thumb'); ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `add_image_size()` in your `functions.php`:

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>


add_image_size( 'your-image', 150);
```

...and then use this in your template:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('your-image'); ?>
```

**REFERENCE** : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

**Some changes in your website** `css`

Try adding  `height:250px; //example you can whatever you want. ...`

in your

```
.avia-content-slider .slide-image, .avia-content-slider .slide-image img
```

I have a screenshot for you

[image]

and have a look ..

Comment: This is for only one image but whats about set image size in bulk?

Comment: It does for all uploaded images .. have a look http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-theme-tip-force-an-image-size/

Comment: How have you tried this? What did not work? This IS the answer as from your question.

Comment: @SanjayRathod -- just updated my answer with a required css change.. Hopefully it might help

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial ... http://ponderwell.net/2011/02/wordpress-featured-images-and-custom-thumbnail-sizes/

Comment: when adding new image sizes via `add_image_size()` you need to regenerate images already uploaded, plugin like this http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ might help

Answer (score 4):

After changing/adding image sizes, as described in Vaibs_Cool's answer, you need to rebuild your previous thumbnails as old ones are not affected, only newly uploaded files.

The classic plugin used for this is

> #### [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)
>
> Allows you to regenerate the thumbnails for your image attachments. This is very handy if you've changed any of your thumbnail dimensions (via Settings -> Media) after previously uploading images or have changed to a theme with different featured post image dimensions.

There's [another plugin always cited](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/), but I've never used as RT works well.

Check the following search results in WordPress Answers regarding both plugins, this will lead to interesting discussions about the topic: [**[ 1 ]**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22regenerate%20thumbnails%22) and [**[ 2 ]**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=ajax-thumbnail-rebuild).

Answer (score 2):

/////// **Adding custom feature image size** //////////////////

add_image_size( $new_size_name, $width, $height, $crop);

**USAGE :**

let's say that you need width = 100 and height = 300

insert next code at your theme **functions.php** file

**add_image_size( "test_size", 100, 300, true );**

Use next code at any place you want :

```
<? echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'test_size'); ?>
```

**NOTICE :** *if you test it and nothing happen .. you just need to remove the feature image and uplaod it again with another name .

**NOTICE :** $crop =  False - Soft proportional crop mode ; True - Hard crop mode.

> // reference
>   :http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size
>
> // reference :add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );

Answer (score 1):

you just add the some css code.for particular that thumbnail images. like this ,

**.slide-entry a img {hight:248px; width:248px;}**

in your style.css.

Answer (score 1):

You should always search in WordPress Codex for that first!

See if this article helps you: "https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes"