# Wordpress : setting thumbnail size on woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

I try to resize all the image thumbnail on the same size (edit function.php, installplugin regenerates thumbnail, setting-> media setting and also on woocommerce-> setting-> display-> product images)

I also try to edit the style.css like on the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910027/how-to-create-thumbnails-of-the-same-size) but I got nothing

Different size

[image]

There is the thumbnail I want

[image: there is the thumbnail i want]

Thx for your advice

Fix => i just set the Height on css  with 100%.

thx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have regenerate all thumbnail again than after you can see results...

Comment: i also did that  but nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

### Thumbnail Types

- **Single Product Image:** Largest thumbnail on the product details page.
- **Catalog Images:** Medium sized thumbnail used in product loops (e.g., categories, related products, up-sells, cross-sells, etc.).
- **Product Thumbnails:** Smallest thumbnail used in product galleries on the single product pages, the cart and widgets.

*Note: these settings are located in **WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display***

### Input the data and regenerate the thumbnails

Now that all thumbnail image sizes for our specific theme are known, we can add new dimensions to ensure that future thumbnails will be this size or larger.

In WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display, be sure that the maximum image sizes are at least as big as the dimensions your theme is rendering for those thumbnails. Then Save Changes.

Any new product images that are uploaded will now have thumbnails in these settings, and should appear without distortion or blurriness.

> **Note:** Saving changes does not automatically update all previously
>   uploaded product imagery. To update old images, WordPress needs to
>   regenerate the thumbnails. A great plugin that does just that is
>   **[Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)**.

Comment: hi @purvik7373 thx for your  concern, can u open my website ad staging.solusisika.com => and open All Product menu. so you can se the last product  is not at the same  size. and the next page also/. 
can u help me there is a product thumbnail, catalog, or sigle product? and what size i can add? ty